# Kubernetes Disk Pressure warning when 10GB Allocated to boot disk per node

Tags: kubernetes

Just wondering how I can allocate storage to a node, because despite my terraform config specifying 10GB of SSD space for boot, it says there is 0 bytes allocatable to storage. This is causing a lot of pod evictions.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal behavior, your 10GB is for docker images, system and so on.
10GB is just, not enough for all required components, 15GB should be sufficient but I strongly recommend using at least 25GB.

For storage allocation, you should use [pv](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/), node storage is only used when you set [emptydir](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#emptydir) as volumes.